# Redirect webpage in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a javascript file with functions that allow me to redirect to another page. But it is not redirected. This is my code:

on my functions.js

```
function openUrl(url) {        
    window.location = url;
}
```

on my php page

```
<script>openUrl('<?=$my_url?>');</script>
<script src="./functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Look at the source in your browser, and make sure the url is populated. Also check for errors in your browser's console.

Comment: try  window.location.href = url;

Answer (score 0):

**Order matters**

You call `openUrl`, which (if you have looked at the Console in your browser's developer tools) is throwing a ReferenceError because it isn't defined.

**Then** you load your functions.js which defines `openUrl` (but by then it is too late).

---

That said, if you are generating an HTML document which immediately goes to a new URL with JS then you should probably be simply issuing a 301 or 302 redirect response instead of an HTML document in the first place.

Comment: Yes I saw that the problem was that I defined the javascript file too late.

That said, I am trying to open deeplinks in a specific application. I don't know if it is possible to do this without an html document ...

Comment: I am currently using php  `header() ` to redirect pages, but now I need to open the link directly in the application, if it is installed on the device. This seems not to be possible without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

switch these two lines

```html
<script src="./functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>openUrl('<?=$my_url?>');</script>
```